# Search for complete substring within "keyword" in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, substring, wildcard, n-gram

I have an index with 500 million documents. Each document is essentially a "keyword" / string of letters and digits (no spaces or punctuations). The strings are on average 10 letters and between 3 and 40 characters long.

I want to be able to swiftly find documents where the keyword field contains a certain substring.

I read that "wildcard" search (*abc*) is slow and not scaleable (prefixed wildcard).

I have now focused on n-grams. Ideally I figure that I should set "min" and "max" to 3 and 40. But if I set both to 3 and a minimum_should_match to 100% on the query, I can get a good result (without adding the tons of extra storage for ngram sized 4 - 40). The drawback seems to be that I get some unwanted results, such as searching for "dabc" would also match "abcd".

**My question is, how to solve my goal in the best possible way (performance and storage).**

Am I trying to reinvent the wheel? Should I just go with ngram min: 3 and max: 40?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try indexing the string with several different analysis strategies and then use ngrams to filter out documents that definitely are not part of what you are looking for and then use wildcards for the remaining ones. Your ngram filter will return some false positives but that is OK because your wildcard filter will fix that. You are trading off space vs. performance here. Smaller ngrams means more false positives (but less space used) and more work for your wildcard filter.

I'd suggest experimenting with a few approaches here before drawing any conclusions on performance and size here.

Instead of a wildcard you could also try a regexp query. This might be a bit cheaper to run than wildcard queries and you can combine it with the ngrams filter approach.

Comment: I like the approach, but when I add a wildcard part to the query the performance is as slow as using only the wildcard: {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "abcdefg"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "name": "\*abcdefg\*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}  The ngram part takes 75 msec, while adding the wildcard jumps up to 3000...

Comment: Ended up using 3grams (3:3) and then filtering in python. Since I could not get good wildcard performance in Elastic and the results from the ngram scan was a mere 500 hits or so.